# JQuery: input change -> find parent -> find next input -> value returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the next closest input of same class or different class that is available in the next row div child it says undefined am unable to get it.

**[[Fiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/dyN67/6/)**

```js
$(".std_amt").change(function() {
      alert($(this).parent('.row').next(".row").children("input.std_amt").val());
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="form-group ">
    
          <input class="form-control std_amt" type="text" name="relative_name_0" id="relative_name_0" value="">
          <label class="help-inline"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="form-group ">
    
          <input class="form-control std_amt" type="text" name="relative_name_1" id="relative_name_1" value="">
          <label class="help-inline"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you want alert when you lose focus from first input or for both??

Comment: .parent('.row') is not the parent....

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt on loosing focus find the next div closest to it or find the next closest input of same or different class and alert its value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `closest` instead of `parent` like below

```js
$(".std_amt").change(function() {
  alert($(this).closest('.row').next(".row").find("input.std_amt").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <input class="form-control std_amt" type="text" name="relative_name_0" id="relative_name_0" value="">
      <label class="help-inline"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <input class="form-control std_amt" type="text" name="relative_name_1" id="relative_name_1" value="">
      <label class="help-inline"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont want with id i want with class like find the closet next div and inside it find the closest input of same class or if i mention different and alert its value

Comment: @Shaik Updated!

Comment: thanks did some alteration working fine i guess!! :)

Comment: FYI, If there are three rows of inputs, and you are on the second, this is not going to select the next one. It will select the first row.

Comment: @Shaik If you will use `next` you will get `undefined` when you change the second input because you are using same class in both input

Comment: i got it i made the alteration working as needed thanks

Answer (score 2):

`.parent('.row')` looks at the direct parent, it does NOT climb the tree. You need to use `closest('.row')` to reference the row. And you should use `find()` and not `children()` since the input is not a direct child.

```
$(this).closest('.row').next(".row").find("input.std_amt")
```

Comment: thanks for the reply please can you make the same in action i have tried with closest it dint work out good..

Comment: altered it, missed that you use children also, same issue as parent, just in the opposite direction.